# Blackberry runtime error: FRIDG: could not find img/logo.png

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I recently had to prepare a BB app for submission to the BB app world, but I have an issue when running the app. Basically, I've created a new Blackberry project, using the "use existing source" option to point to the sources I've got from the developer that actually developed this app. Building the application just works, but when I want to start the app it immediately quits with a NullPointerException.

When debugging the application, the debugger halts at the following line:

```
Bitmap bitmaplogo = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/logo.png").getBitmap();
```

With the following error:

```
[0.0] FRIDG: could not find img/logo.png
```

I do have an img/logo.png, which is located in /res/img/logo.png. Attempts of specifying the path as "res/img/logo.png", "/res/img/logo.png", "logo.png" have not worked. I personally don't think that's the issue here, this exact code base works perfectly for another developer. I'm more inclined to start looking into tooling, JDK/JRE versions, project settings. Maybe resource files should be explicitly included in the build?

Some other information:

- My Blackberry project uses Blackberry JRE 5.0.0 as the JRE system library
- I have Oracle Java SDK 6 Update 26 installed
- Using Blackberry Java Plugin for Eclipse 1.3.0
- On Windows XP SP2

Has anyone encountered the same issue before?

Comment: I am having the same problem. "FRIDG: could not find images/xxx.gif " I am using PhoneGap and what I am doing is, calling a URL using ajax call and parsing its response and display data to user. I am getting error all the images that are in response as missing in simulator output window. I am able to run my blackberry project in Ripple chrome plugin without any issue. all data are loaded just fine..  Any Idea, Please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Filenames and extensions are case sensitive. logo.png and logo.PNG are different files from application's point of view. So, be careful with naming files and folders.
2. The root folder for images you get in your application is the root folder of your source files package.

For instance, if you have the following folder structure:

```
YourProject
   src\
      com\
        company\
             etc\
   img\
```

Then the root folder for your images will be: `YourProject\src`

Image files located in `YourProject\img` folder are invisible for your application code, unless `img` folder is located in `YourProject\src` and the full path is:

```
YourProject\src\img
```

and your image file has the full path like that:

```
YourProject\src\img\logo.png
```

In this case you can load the image via specifying it's path: `img\logo.png`

and without it, just via specifying: `logo.png`

Specifying the full path is recommended if you have several images with similar filenames.

If you have several files `logo.png` in your project, and you load it via specifying only file name "logo.png" then the first found image from your project will be loaded.

Resume: transfer your `img` folder into the `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same as your problem, but when I get those types of errors, it usually means that I need to force the project in Eclipse to refresh (right-click on project and choose Refresh) and then rebuild.